# Adding a plot title to a gauge plot and adjust output

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I add a title to this gauge plot? Specifically, I want a title that changes according to the input value. For example, if it is in the "red region", the title should be "extreme danger", while the "blue region" should have the title of "moderate danger", and so on. Also, how would I make the function display the number with a percent next to it? For example, when I do `dangerGauge(10)` I end up with a gauge, and underneath it the number 10. I would like it to display "10%". Also, some of the numbers I'm using are irrational, so I would like for it to display only to two decimal places. E.g. `dangerGauge(pi)' should give me "3.14%". Any help is appreciated!

```
dangerGauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0, 10, 35, 65, 90, 100)) {
  require(ggplot2)
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
    x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="blue")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="yellow")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[4],breaks[5]),aes(x,y),fill="orange")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[5],breaks[6]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
    geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
              aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}
dangerGauge(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    library(dplyr)
dangerGauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0, 10, 35, 65, 90, 100)) {
      require(ggplot2)
      get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
        th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
        th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
        th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
        x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
        y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
        return(data.frame(x,y))
      }

pos_per <-  paste(round(pos,2),"%")#create output for gauge with % 

pos <-ifelse(pos>=100,100,round(pos,1)) #round input value so title below works with decimals 
title <- case_when(
between(pos,0,9.9) ~ "no danger",
between(pos,10,34.9)~ "some danger",
between(pos,35,64.9)~ "moderate danger",
between(pos,65,89.9) ~ "high danger",
between(pos,90,100) ~ "extreme danger",
pos >100 ~ "extreme danger")
#create title


  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="blue")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="yellow")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[4],breaks[5]),aes(x,y),fill="orange")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[5],breaks[6]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
    geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
              aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos_per,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) +
labs(title = title)
}
dangerGauge(110)
dangerGauge(pi)
```

Comment: when I try to use values above 100%, I want it to be interpreted as 100%, but the display shows the correct value. How do I fix this?

Comment: Edited to treat values above 100% as 100%

Comment: Thanks! I want the display of the value underneath the gauge to show up as 110%, but it shows it as 100%.